# screen record(Capture) using ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, red5, screen-capture

I developed a video calling application using Actionscript and Red5. Now i want to include screen sharing,my idea is to capture screen video and publish it to red5 server but i didn't find any API to capture/Record screen in AS3. 
 Can any one tell me Is there any calls to capture screen in As3.
 When i searched, I found these statements.but i didn't find any luck.

```
screenCapture = ScreenCapture.getInstance();
                  screenCapture.source = stage;
                  screenCapture.fps = 12;
                  screenCapture.size( 400, 300 );
                  screenCapture.x = 400;
                  screenCapture.y = 250;
                  stage.addChild( screenCapture );
```

Comment: There's none. AS3 can only capture its own window, Flash player does not have access to what happens outside.

Comment: Is there any better language to record the screen and send to red5 server?

Comment: Brutal, but C++ or C# should do. You basically need to create a service that has access to the root OS window, and then make people run your software to share screen. Or, use TeamViewer or any other available tool on a per-request basis.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to capture the screen using Java or some C/C++, but it is basically impossible to do in AS3. If you want to do this, you have two choices:

1. Find or create an ANE for AIR which captures the screen
2. Find or create a "virtual" camera that captures the screen and is exposed to AS3 as a Camera device